# Fixed positioning of footer takes content out of the container - CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I have two unordered lists `<ul>` in a `<footer>` tag. List items are displayed horizontally and both lists are separated by some space between them. What i want is to fix the position of the footer at the bottom of the browser.

**Problem:**

When I try to set the position of footer to **fixed** using `position` property of `CSS`, one list gets out of the `footer` container but its position remains same, i.e horizontal to first list that is inside the `footer` container.

If the position of `footer` is set to **relative**, 2nd list comes back inside the `footer` container.

**Question:**

What am I doing wrong here ?

Related code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dVPyvG

Comment: why do you have `left: 835px` on the `list-2`?

Comment: to make the 2nd list to be displayed at the right side of the screen. i want 1st list to be displayed at bottom lest corner and 2nd list to be displayed at bottom right corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *extend* the footer to the whole width of the screen by adding to `footer`:

```
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Instead of the `left: 835px` on the `list-2` you can add `float:right` on the container you want to keep to the right using:

```
.list-container + .list-container {
  float: right;
}
```

See demo below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

footer {
  background: #eee;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0; /* ADDED */
  right: 0; /* ADDED */
  border: solid 5px red;
}

footer ul {
  line-height: 50px;
}

.list-container {
  display: inline-block;
}

footer ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#list-1 {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

#list-2 {
  position: relative;
  /*left: 835px;*/
}
.list-container + .list-container {
  float: right; /* ADDED */
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Fake Google Homepage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fakeGoogle.css">
  <!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

  <footer>
    <div class="list-container">
      <ul id="list-1">
        <li>Advertising</li>
        <li>Business</li>
        <li>About</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="list-container">
      <ul id="list-2">
        <li>Privacy</li>
        <li>Terms</li>
        <li>Settings</li>
        <li>Use Google.com</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: that works fine but i want to know what caused that problem in the first place ? what was i doing wrong ?

Comment: you were giving `835px` and *positioning* to the right side... but this works in your screen size only... what should be done is put the `footer` at 100% `width` and *float* the container to the right end of it... :)

Answer (score 1):

try this snippet:

```
footer{
    background: #eee;
    height: 50px; 
    position: absolute;   //use absolute for position
    bottom: 0px;
    width:100%;           //add width
    border: solid 5px red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of your footer container using `width:100%` or `width:100vw`.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

footer{
    background: #eee;
    width:100%;
    height: 50px; 
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    border: solid 5px red;
}

footer ul{
    line-height: 50px;
}

.list-container{
    display: inline-block;
}

footer ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px; 
}

#list-1{
    padding-left: 15px;
}

#list-2{
    position: relative;
    left: 835px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Fake Google Homepage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fakeGoogle.css">
        <!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <footer>
            <div class="list-container">
               <ul id="list-1">
                    <li>Advertising</li>
                    <li>Business</li>
                    <li>About</li>   
                </ul> 
            </div>
            
            <div class="list-container">
                <ul id="list-2">
                    <li>Privacy</li>
                    <li>Terms</li>
                    <li>Settings</li>
                    <li>Use Google.com</li>    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </footer>
        
    </body>
</html>
```